# How to determine the number of solutions of a given instance using Mathsat

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, mathsat

Mathsat supports the command `check-allsat` and Z3 does not support it.  Please consider the following example:

```
(declare-fun m () Bool)
(declare-fun p () Bool)
(declare-fun b () Bool)
(declare-fun c () Bool)
(declare-fun r () Bool)
(declare-fun al () Bool)
(declare-fun all () Bool)
(declare-fun la () Bool)
(declare-fun lal () Bool)
(declare-fun g () Bool)
(declare-fun a () Bool)
(define-fun conjecture () Bool
(and (= (and (not r) c) m) (= p m) (= b m) (= c (not g)) (= (and (not al) (not all)) r)
(=(and la b) al) 
(= (and al la lal) all) (= (and (not g) p a) la) (= (and (not g) (or la a)) lal)))
(assert conjecture)
(check-allsat (m p b c r al all la lal g a))
```

Executing this code with mathsat all the consistent assignments are obtained.  The question is how to determine the number of such consistent assignments using Mathsat?

Comment: "The question is how to determine the number of such consistent assignments using Mathsat?" Do you mean "...using Z3?"?  If so, have you tried the APIs with model generation, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395391/z3-finding-all-satisfying-models/13398853#13398853 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578627/model-counting-in-z3py

Comment: I mean using Mathsat:  how to count the solutions using Mathsat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any command to count the number of solutions. But this can be done easily using MathSAT's API. Create a counter, and increase it each time MathSAT notifies.

```
static int counter = 0;
static int my_callback(msat_term *model, int size, void *user_data)
{
   counter++; return 1;
}
...
msat_all_sat(env, important, 4, my_callback, &data);
```