# Is it possible to enumerate all models of Max-SMT?

Tags: z3

z3 returns the number of unsat clauses for a Max-SMT problem together with only one model. I wonder if I can list them all (e.g. using API).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395391/z3-finding-all-satisfying-models), you can use the generated model to add a constraint to prevent the generated model and run the solver again. In your case however, I believe you will also need to check the number of constraints that are broken, after generating a new model, to ensure that you don't break your optimality constraints.