# How to get solutions for an expression in Z3

Tags: z3, smt

I am trying to do something in theory very easy with Z3, but I am not sure how to do it.

So imagine I have this code in C:

```
int c;
if (c>=65 && C<91)
    int d = c + 32;
```

I would like to know possible solutions for d, for example 97. I try to express the problem in Z3 like this:

```
(declare-const c Int)
(assert (> c 64))
(assert (< c 91))
(define-fun d() Int
 (+ 32 c)
)
(assert (> d 0))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

But in this way I get solutions for c not for the variable d.

How should I do it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get one solution for d, you can use:

```
(declare-const c Int)
(declare-const d Int)

(assert (> c 64))
(assert (< c 91))

(assert (= d (+ c 32)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

If you want to find all solutions for d, you can repeatedly negate models and add them as constraints.  See Taylor's response here: [Z3: finding all satisfying models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395391/z3-finding-all-satisfying-models)

Edit: Adding on, a slightly more direct translation of the program would use:

```
(>= 65 c)
```

rather than

```
(> 64 c)
```