# How to get a list of integers from a given set of possible integers in z3?

Tags: z3, constraint-programming, z3py

Minimal example is the following: Given a set of possible integers `[1, 2, 3]` create an arbitrary list of size 5 using z3py. Duplicates are allowed.

The expected result is something like `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` or `[3, 1, 2, 2, 3]`, etc.

How to tackle this problem and how to implement 'choosing'? Finally, I would like to find all solutions which can be done by adding additional constraints as explained in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395391/z3-finding-all-satisfying-models). Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
from z3 import *

def choose(elts, acceptable):
    s = Solver()
    s.add(And([Or([x == v for v in acceptable]) for x in Ints(elts)]))

    models = []
    while s.check() == sat:
        m = s.model ()
        if not m:
            break
        models.append(m)
        block = Not(And([v() == m[v] for v in m]))
        s.add(block)

    return models

print choose('a b c d e', [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Amazing! I see you don't use any `Array` or quantifiers but you simply define a variable for each field separately and place the constraint. Perfect, thanks!