# Z3 (Python) native method for counting the number of models

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py, theorem-proving

In Z3 (Python), I found a way to see which are the models of a formula. See the post [Z3: finding all satisfying models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395391/z3-finding-all-satisfying-models) and a piece of code of it below:

```
a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')

s = Solver()
s.add(1 <= a)
s.add(a <= 20)
s.add(1 <= b)
s.add(b <= 20)
s.add(a >= 2*b)

while s.check() == sat:
  print s.model()
  s.add(Or(a != s.model()[a], b != s.model()[b]))
```

Now, I would like to count **how many models are there**. Of course, I could add a counter in the loop:

```
def count_models (s):
   counter = 0
   while s.check() == sat:
     print s.model()
     s.add(Or(a != s.model()[a], b != s.model()[b]))
     counter = counter + 1
   return counter
```

However, I would like to know whether there is any native function to do so. Something like `s.count_models`. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is the only way as z3 stands today. The way to count models is to generate each one-by-one and add them up. Any internal method would essentially do the same.

Keep in mind that if you have an unbounded domain (such as unbounded integers as you have in your example), there might be infinite number of models; thus your loop is not always guaranteed to terminate.

Model counting in SAT and SMT are both research problems. Here're a couple of references for further reading:

- In the SAT context, see: [https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~sabhar/chapters/ModelCounting-SAT-Handbook-prelim.pdf](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Esabhar/chapters/ModelCounting-SAT-Handbook-prelim.pdf).
- In the SMT context, see: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00236-017-0297-2

### Note on generating models

Generating all models in z3 can be done faster than the algorithm you've used. See [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-blocking-evaluations](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-blocking-evaluations) for details. The idea is still to enumerate, but using better splits of the search-space instead of randomly walking it.

Comment: Thanks also for the last comment. You mean with examples like: give me all the models for `Exists a:: (a>1000)`, right?

Comment: Yes. Or even simpler. `Exists x. True`.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot! Just wanted a clear example for the unbounded integer domain heheh