# Can I use a SMT program's result in another SMT expression?

Tags: z3

I would like to use a model's output (in my case sat and unsat only) in another model. Here, a model is a satisfying assignment to constants involved in a set of logical formulas (Z3 expressions in this case). My objective can be briefly explained as follows.

My problem can be described in detail as follows: I have a formalized a problem P, a set logical formulas (expressions) corresponding to a number of constraints (C). Among the expressions, one (e.g., Ai > 0) is my objective. Executing the model/formalization P returns sat, if all the constraints are satisfiable. Note that, Ai = 0 is always possible.
Now, I want to find the set of assignments to a particular set of variables corresponds to the constraints (C) that ensure that Ai > 0 (for any i) is not possible.
Currently, I am solving the problem by writing a program (in C#) that develop a DFS-based searching algorithm of the constraints (i.e., constraint values) and execute P to see if the result is false with the help of "push/pop". Though I have tried to make the search better, it does not help me a lot. It is very inefficient for a large problem size. It would be great if I could create another SMT program (model) utilizing P for searching such a satisfiable set.

The current formalization of problem P (a short SMT LIB 2 version of the original problem) is as follows:

```
(declare-fun th1 () Real)
(declare-fun th2 () Real)
(declare-fun th3 () Real)
(declare-fun th4 () Real)
(declare-fun th5 () Real)

(declare-fun l1 () Real)
(declare-fun l2 () Real)
(declare-fun l3 () Real)
(declare-fun l4 () Real)
(declare-fun l5 () Real)
(declare-fun l6 () Real)
(declare-fun l7 () Real)

(declare-fun p1 () Real)
(declare-fun p2 () Real)
(declare-fun p3 () Real)
(declare-fun p4 () Real)
(declare-fun p5 () Real)

(declare-fun sl1 () Int)
(declare-fun sl2 () Int)
(declare-fun sl3 () Int)
(declare-fun sl4 () Int)
(declare-fun sl5 () Int)
(declare-fun sl6 () Int)
(declare-fun sl7 () Int)

(declare-fun sp1 () Int)
(declare-fun sp2 () Int)
(declare-fun sp3 () Int)
(declare-fun sp4 () Int)
(declare-fun sp5 () Int)

(declare-fun a1 () Int)
(declare-fun a2 () Int)
(declare-fun a3 () Int)
(declare-fun a4 () Int)
(declare-fun a5 () Int)

(declare-fun na () Int)
(declare-fun ns () Int)
(declare-fun attack () Bool)

;;;; System
(assert (and      (= l1 (* (- th2 th1) 17.0))
        (= l2 (* (- th5 th1) 4.5))
        (= l3 (* (- th3 th2) 5.05))
        (= l4 (* (- th4 th2) 5.65))
        (= l5 (* (- th5 th2) 5.75))
        (= l6 (* (- th4 th3) 5.85))
        (= l7 (* (- th5 th4) 23.75))        

        (= p1 (+ l1 l2))
        (= p2 (+ l1 l3 l4 l5))
        (= p3 (+ l3 l6))
        (= p4 (+ l4 l6 l7))
        (= p5 (+ l2 l5 l7))
        )
)

;;;; Secured measurements
(assert (and    (or (= sl1 0) (= sl1 1))
        (or (= sl2 0) (= sl2 1))
        (or (= sl3 0) (= sl3 1))
        (or (= sl4 0) (= sl4 1))
        (or (= sl5 0) (= sl5 1))
        (or (= sl6 0) (= sl6 1))
        (or (= sl7 0) (= sl7 1))

        (or (= sp1 0) (= sp1 1))
        (or (= sp2 0) (= sp2 1))
        (or (= sp3 0) (= sp3 1))
        (or (= sp4 0) (= sp4 1))
        (or (= sp5 0) (= sp5 1))        
        )
)        

(assert (and    (=> (not (= l1 0.0)) (= sl1 0))
        (=> (not (= l2 0.0)) (= sl2 0))
        (=> (not (= l3 0.0)) (= sl3 0))
        (=> (not (= l4 0.0)) (= sl4 0))
        (=> (not (= l5 0.0)) (= sl5 0))
        (=> (not (= l6 0.0)) (= sl6 0))
        (=> (not (= l7 0.0)) (= sl7 0))     

        (=> (not (= p1 0.0)) (= sp1 0))
        (=> (not (= p2 0.0)) (= sp2 0))
        (=> (not (= p3 0.0)) (= sp3 0))
        (=> (not (= p4 0.0)) (= sp4 0))
        (=> (not (= p5 0.0)) (= sp5 0))          
    )
)

(assert (and (= sl1 1) (= sl2 1)))

;;;; Attacks
(assert (and    (or (= a1 0) (= a1 1))
        (or (= a2 0) (= a2 1))
        (or (= a3 0) (= a3 1))
        (or (= a4 0) (= a4 1))
        (or (= a5 0) (= a5 1))      
    )
)

(assert (and
        (= (not (= th1 0.0)) (= a1 1))
        (= (not (= th2 0.0)) (= a2 1))
        (= (not (= th3 0.0)) (= a3 1))
        (= (not (= th4 0.0)) (= a4 1))
        (= (not (= th5 0.0)) (= a5 1))      
    )
)

(assert (= th1 0.0)) // Base condition
(assert (= na (+ a1 a2 a3 a4 a5)))
(assert (=> attack (> na 1)))


;;;; Check for satisfiable model

(assert attack)

(check-sat)
(get-model)
(exit)
```

I want synthesize the security measurements (i.e., find the assignments of 'sl' and 'sp' terms) so that there would be no attack (i.e., na will be 0) given the constraints, e.g., as follows:

```
(assert (= ns (+ sl1 sl2 sl3 sl4 sl5 sl6 sl7 sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4 sp5)))
(assert (<= ns 4))
```

In this case, the assertion (i.e., '(assert (and (= sl1 1) (= sl2 1)))' ) will be commented. Currently, I have developed a C# program that take an assignment of 'sl' and 'sp', assert them like (assert (and (= sl1 1) (= sl2 1) ...))', and execute the given program to see if there is any attack possible. I am done when the program returns unsat (i.e., na > 1 is not possible). Is there any way to solve the problem using SMT (Z3) only?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "model"?  It sounds like you mean model to be a description of a system (e.g., a security policy that prevents or allows an attack path, which you then use Z3 in some way to prove the presence or absence of), whereas you could mean model in the model theoretic sense, e.g., a satisfying assignment to constants involved in a set of logical formulas (Z3 expressions in this case).  See the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395391/z3-finding-all-satisfying-models     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000953/z3-check-if-model-is-unique

Comment: Both way, the model can be defined. However, I think the second definition, i.e.,  a satisfying assignment to constants involved in a set of logical formulas (Z3 expressions in this case) would be the best to define the model

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example of P, C, and Ais to help understand what you're asking (ideally using appropriate sorts for everything involved, e.g., in SMT-LIB format)?  It sounds roughly like you are solving the SAT problem by searching through values for constraints C, which is somewhat hard to understand what you're asking since you could probably encode this and get Z3 to solve the SAT problem for you, so an example will really help.

Comment: I have updated my question with the example code regarding my problem. I wish now it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for clearing up the question.  If I've understood things, you can perform the search for `sli` and `spj` values using Z3, but you cannot do this using SMT-LIB only, you need to use an API.  The idea is to use the models (satisfying assignments) from one sat check as constraints in future checks, as explained in detail in these answers:

[Z3: finding all satisfying models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395391/z3-finding-all-satisfying-models)

[Z3: Check if model is unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000953/z3-check-if-model-is-unique)

[(Z3Py) checking all solutions for equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867611/z3py-checking-all-solutions-for-equation)

Here's your example encoded in the Python API (z3py link: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/KHzm):

```
s = Solver()

th1, th2, th3, th4, th5 = Reals('th1 th2 th3 th4 th5')
th = { 'th1' : th1, 'th2' : th2, 'th3' : th3, 'th4' : th4, 'th5' : th5}
l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7 = Reals('l1 l2 l3 l4 l5 l6 l7')
l = { 'l1' : l1, 'l2' : l2, 'l3' : l3, 'l4' : l4, 'l5' : l5, 'l6' : l6, 'l7' : l7 }
p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 = Reals('p1 p2 p3 p4 p5')
p = { 'p1' : p1, 'p2' : p2, 'p3' : p3, 'p4' : p4, 'p5' : p5 }
sl1, sl2, sl3, sl4, sl5, sl6, sl7 = Ints('sl1 sl2 sl3 sl4 sl5 sl6 sl7')
sl = { 'sl1' : sl1, 'sl2' : sl2, 'sl3' : sl3, 'sl4' : sl4, 'sl5' : sl5, 'sl6' : sl6, 'sl7' : sl7 }
sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, sp5 = Ints('sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4 sp5')
sp = { 'sp1' : sp1, 'sp2' : sp2, 'sp3' : sp3, 'sp4' : sp4, 'sp5' : sp5 }
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 = Ints('a1 a2 a3 a4 a5')
a = { 'a1' : a1, 'a2' : a2, 'a3' : a3, 'a4' : a4, 'a5' : a5 }
na, ns = Ints('na ns')
attack = Bool('attack')
n = { 'na' : na, 'ns' : ns, 'attack' : attack}
dict_decl = dict(th.items() + l.items() + p.items() + sl.items() + sp.items() + a.items() + n.items() )

assertions = []
assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert (and      (= l1 (* (- th2 th1) 17.0)) (= l2 (* (- th5 th1) 4.5)) (= l3 (* (- th3 th2) 5.05)) (= l4 (* (- th4 th2) 5.65)) (= l5 (* (- th5 th2) 5.75)) (= l6 (* (- th4 th3) 5.85)) (= l7 (* (- th5 th4) 23.75)) (= p1 (+ l1 l2)) (= p2 (+ l1 l3 l4 l5)) (= p3 (+ l3 l6)) (= p4 (+ l4 l6 l7)) (= p5 (+ l2 l5 l7))))', decls=dict_decl))
assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert (and    (or (= sl1 0) (= sl1 1)) (or (= sl2 0) (= sl2 1)) (or (= sl3 0) (= sl3 1)) (or (= sl4 0) (= sl4 1)) (or (= sl5 0) (= sl5 1)) (or (= sl6 0) (= sl6 1)) (or (= sl7 0) (= sl7 1)) (or (= sp1 0) (= sp1 1)) (or (= sp2 0) (= sp2 1)) (or (= sp3 0) (= sp3 1)) (or (= sp4 0) (= sp4 1)) (or (= sp5 0) (= sp5 1))        ))', decls=dict_decl))
assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert (and    (=> (not (= l1 0.0)) (= sl1 0)) (=> (not (= l2 0.0)) (= sl2 0)) (=> (not (= l3 0.0)) (= sl3 0)) (=> (not (= l4 0.0)) (= sl4 0)) (=> (not (= l5 0.0)) (= sl5 0)) (=> (not (= l6 0.0)) (= sl6 0)) (=> (not (= l7 0.0)) (= sl7 0))      (=> (not (= p1 0.0)) (= sp1 0)) (=> (not (= p2 0.0)) (= sp2 0)) (=> (not (= p3 0.0)) (= sp3 0)) (=> (not (= p4 0.0)) (= sp4 0)) (=> (not (= p5 0.0)) (= sp5 0))           ))', decls=dict_decl))
assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert (and (= sl1 1) (= sl2 1)))', decls=dict_decl))
assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert (and    (or (= a1 0) (= a1 1))(or (= a2 0) (= a2 1))(or (= a3 0) (= a3 1))(or (= a4 0) (= a4 1))(or (= a5 0) (= a5 1))      ))', decls=dict_decl))
assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert (and (= (not (= th1 0.0)) (= a1 1))(= (not (= th2 0.0)) (= a2 1))(= (not (= th3 0.0)) (= a3 1))(= (not (= th4 0.0)) (= a4 1))(= (not (= th5 0.0)) (= a5 1))      ))', decls=dict_decl))
assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert (= ns (+ sl1 sl2 sl3 sl4 sl5 sl6 sl7 sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4 sp5)))', decls=dict_decl))
assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert (<= ns 4))', decls=dict_decl))
#assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert (and (= sl1 1) (= sl2 1)))', decls=dict_decl)) # commented as suggested
assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert (= th1 0.0))', decls=dict_decl))
assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert (= na (+ a1 a2 a3 a4 a5)))', decls=dict_decl))
assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert (=> attack (> na 1)))', decls=dict_decl))
assertions.append(parse_smt2_string('(assert attack)', decls=dict_decl))

print assertions

s.add(assertions)

synthesized = []

iters = 0
while s.check() == sat:
  print "Iteration " + str(iters)
  print s.model()
  avoid = []
  # key step: add constraint to prevent any values assigned (if possible) to constants from being equal to their satisfying assignments (models) in this sat iteration
  for sli in sl.values():
    avoid.append(sli != s.model()[sli])
  for spi in sp.values():
    avoid.append(spi != s.model()[spi])
  s.add(Or(avoid))
  # end key step
  synthesized.append(avoid)
  print avoid
  iters = iters + 1
  # unless you know how to guarantee termination (e.g., there is a constraint ensuring the slis and spis take values in finite sets)
  if iters >= 1000:
    break

print "Done"
print synthesized # all the constraints
```

Apologies for all the constants and numbers, I just used the quickest translation of your SMT-LIB script, but it ended up being rather cumbersome, I would use iterators everywhere.  This generated the following constraints over the `sli` and `spj` constants:

```
[[sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 0, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 0, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 1, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 0, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 0, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 1, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 0, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 1, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 0, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 1, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 1, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 0, sp2 ≠ 1, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 1, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 1, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 0, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 1, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 1, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 0, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 0, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 1, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 0, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 1, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 0, sl6 ≠ 1, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 1, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 0, sl6 ≠ 1, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 0, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 1, sl6 ≠ 1, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 0, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 0, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 1, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 1, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 1, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 0, sp2 ≠ 0, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 1, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 0, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 0, sp2 ≠ 1, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0], [sl4 ≠ 0, sl5 ≠ 0, sl6 ≠ 0, sl7 ≠ 0, sl1 ≠ 1, sl2 ≠ 1, sl3 ≠ 0, sp1 ≠ 1, sp2 ≠ 1, sp3 ≠ 0, sp4 ≠ 0, sp5 ≠ 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks again. However, I already mentioned you that I implemented the program with the help of Z3 .Net API. In order to find the secured measurements, I have developed a tree-based searching process (DFS-based solution). That means, I have also tried like your idea. However, these ideas are not efficient. In this problem, the search space is nCr, where n is the number of measurements to be secured (here, 12) and r is the number of maximum secured measurements. You know this is a small example. For larger problems, n > 100 and r > 30. You can easily understand the overhead. :(

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, then you are precisely looking for (universal) quantification. Excuse my pseudo-notation, but are you not looking for a satisfying assignment to the free variables (`config_params`) in the following?

```
config_constraints(config_params) -> forall attack_params: not attack_constraints(attack_params, config_params)
```

where the `()` notation merely indicates which variable (sets) the constraints depend upon. I'm pretty sure that quantifiers are supported in the .Net API, as they are in the Java API.

Comment: Thank you for your response, though I could not able to solve my problem following your idea. However, I have elaborated my problem description with an example. I hope this will help you be more specific about the solution to my problem.

Comment: Could you explain what was the problem following the idea (insufficient description)? Even after your elaboration, "find the assignments of 'sl' and 'sp' terms) so that there would be no attack" sounds to me as if you need (alternating) quantifiers to correctly specify your problem.

Comment: Actually, though I tried to write the formalization using quantifiers, I could not finish as I did not able to understand which argument I can take for quantifier and which part I can place in the quantifier body. I became really confused. It would be great if you can show me the way looking to my code. Thank you in advance.