# Encoding a language grammar and Enumerating all accepted terminals using Z3 (Z3py)

Tags: z3, z3py

I have a problem that I want to formulate using Z3. However, I not sure what is the best way to do that. Here is a description of what I want to encode and the anticipated output.

If I have a language grammar where x, y and z are non-terminals and "and", "or" and "a" are the language terminals:

1. x ::= y "or" y

   ```
      | y
   ```
2. y ::= z "and" z

   ```
     | z
   ```
3. z ::= "a"

I want first to encode the previous rules and then I want to generate All possible terminal derivations that are accepted by the grammar.

The ultimate output would be :

a and a or a and a

a or a

a and a

a and a or a

a or a and a

...

I do not know where to start. What is the best way to encode the problem?

Any suggestion/guidance is very appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way of using Z3 to generate all possible solutions to a constraint system is to iteratively "forbid" the previously found solution by adding it as a new (negative) constraint. See [Leo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11869410/491216) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867611/).