# How to retrieve all satisfying assignments in SMTLIB2?

Tags: smt, sat

Is there a way to retrieve all satisfying assignments using SMTLIB2 syntax?

The solvers I am using are Z3 and CVC4.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no way to do this in "pure" SMTLIB2, i.e. just with a single file and no external input, if you have an application that can interact with the solver, there's a standard trick to doing this. You run the solver in interactive mode, where you can send it SMTLIB2 commands one at a time, and then interact with it in the following way (pseudocode):

`def get_all_assignments(instance):
  create solver in interactive mode
  for each declaration, assertion, etc. in instance:
    send assertion to solver
  let response := None
  while response is not UNSAT:
    send command '(check-sat)' to solver and get response
    if response is SAT:
      send command '(get-model)' to solver and get model
      print model
      send the solver a new assertion which is the negation of the model`

Effectively, every time you find a satisfying assignment, you add a new constraint to your model that prevents the solver from finding that assignment again, and ask it to re-solve. When the solver returns UNSAT you know that you have found every satisfying assignment.

For further reading on this topic and implementations for Z3, refer to [Z3: finding all satisfying models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395391/z3-finding-all-satisfying-models?rq=1) and [Z3py: checking all solutions for equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867611/z3py-checking-all-solutions-for-equation).