# If there are multiple solutions, can I print them up to 2?

Tags: z3, smt

If one formula has more than one model, is there some way to print them?

I have a problem for which I know there are many solutions. However, if I use the following commands

```
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

`z3` prints the same model twice, instead of giving me two different models.

**Q:** Is there any way to extract multiple, different, models of a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automated way to do this. The usual trick is to assert the negation of the last model, and ask for another one.

See this answer for details: [how to get multiple solutions for z3 solver in smt2 format example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459119/how-to-get-multiple-solutions-for-z3-solver-in-smt2-format-example)