# Checking all solutions for array (as-array) in Z3PY

Tags: z3, solver, z3py

My problem is that I have to get all possible models for an array of the form `as-array`. The code I have done for this is the following:

```
s = Solver()
check = s.check()
while (str(check) == "sat"):
      mod = s.model()
      block = []
      for var in mod.decls():
         block.append(var() != mod[var])
      s.add(Or(block))
      check = s.check()
```

`var` can take values of type `as-array` among others and when I run the line `s.add(Or(block))`, the next time I run the line `check = s.check` it returns unknown

Is there any other way to do it?

------- Edit -------

I have found a way to get all possible models for an array of the form `as-array` that was the previous problem, the way I have done it is to create a variable that represents the size of the array and from i = 0 to i = n (where n is the size), make `a[i]!= x` being "a" the array and "x" the value that takes "a[i]".

My problem now is that I have a datatype of the form "mk-pair" whose first argument is an array of the form `as-array` and an Integer that indicates the size of the array.

When I get a model I have it in the form `mk-pair(as-array, 30)` (for example), being 30 the size of the array.

The problem is that I can't find a way to obtain all the possible models, since if I deny the type of data (a != x, assuming that "a" is the datatype and "x" its value), it returns me unknown and if I do the first (as-array[0] != x), what I am really denying is `as-array`, not the variable "a"(which is of the form mk-pair(as-array, Int) ) and when I ask for models several times I get duplicate results.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequent request. Your blocking clause will have to be modified to account for the possibility of arrays. It should also watch out for data-types, functions, floats, ... Definitely doable, and the code to this answer will get you started: [(Z3Py) checking all solutions for equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867611/z3py-checking-all-solutions-for-equation)

Note that you can't in general "block" functions. Arrays can also be problematic as you will not be able to "recast" them as a blocker if they have an infinite support. (That is, think of an array that maps `i`'th element to value `i`. There's no finite representation of this that you can easily write in SMTLib without quantifiers.) Aside from those considerations, I believe the trick in the above answer can get you far enough, handling most cases.

Comment: I have edited with a possible solution that I found for my previous problem and with a new one.

Comment: In general, arrays and functions cannot be handled in `all-sat` scenarios if they have infinite support. (There would be no way to add a "blocking" clause.) But if they're over finite domains with finitely many elements defined in the model, you can work around by adding a blocking cause for those elements only. Your question is hard to follow though, please post a new one with sample code that people can actually run to replicate. You'll get better answers that way.