# SAT ‒ set maximal number of variables to true

Tags: mathematical-optimization, z3, sat

I wish to solve the following SAT-related problem, preferably using Z3 or some other freely available solver:

Given a set of formulae of predicate logic (without quantifiers or negation) over a set of Boolean variables, find the maximal subset of the variables, such that if `true` is assigned precisely to all variables in this subset, all the formulae are satisfied. The formulae are all of the form `variable => CNF-formula`.

Generally, I want to find an "optimal" solution to the classical SAT problem, which is the valuation assigning `true` to the most variables possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General method

You can use the z3's optimize engine to solve this. Here's an example.

Let's say we have 4 variables `a, b, c, d`, and the predicates are `a -> b&c` and `c & !d`. We first create them and add the constraints to the engine:

```py
from z3 import *

a, b, c, d = Bools('a b c d')
bools = [a, b, c, d]

s = Optimize()
s.add(Implies(a, And(b, c)))
s.add(And(c, Not(d)))
```

Now we keep a counter, and add 1 to it for each true variable:

```py
goal = 0
for v in bools:
    goal = goal + If(v, 1, 0)
```

Finally, we tell z3 to maximize this goal:

```py
s.maximize(goal)
```

We can now query for the optimal model:

```py
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[b = True, a = True, d = False, c = True]
```

from which we can conclude that *a* maximally satisfying subset is `{a, b, c}` for our constraints; which you can easily see is also the only one.

### Using Soft Constraints

Another way to do this would be to add soft-constraints for each boolean instead of creating the `goal` variable, something like this:

```py
from z3 import *

a, b, c, d = Bools('a b c d')

s = Optimize()
s.add(Implies(a, And(b, c)))
s.add(And(c, Not(d)))

s.add_soft(a)
s.add_soft(b)
s.add_soft(c)
s.add_soft(d)

print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This'll produce the exact same output; and is equivalent when all you want to do is maximize the number of `true` assignments. (The first form is more general if you want to prioritize certain variables over others, since you can assign different "integers" instead of `1` to all to insure they are preferable over others.)

Comment: Excellent, thank you. BTW `goal = sum(If(v, 1, 0) for v in bools)` also seems to work.

Comment: And one more question – how to find _all_ optimal assignments? Is there a way to do it other than adding the clause `(!v1 or !v2 or !v3 ...)` after finding each model {v1, v2, v3...} ?

Comment: There's a couple of different ways to get "all-solutions." The basic idea is to iteratively add constraints to refute older models, till you get `unsat`. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867611/z3py-checking-all-solutions-for-equation