# simple z3 question - why x*x-1==0 does not return both roots

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I'm just trying to study z3 and its .NET interface. I'm using PowerShell for that, to make it a bit more interactive. And my first `hello world` is below.

```
$ctx = [Microsoft.Z3.Context]::new()

$x = $ctx.MkConst("x", $ctx.MkIntSort())
$zero = $ctx.MkNumeral(0, $ctx.MkIntSort())
$one = $ctx.MkNumeral(1, $ctx.MkIntSort())

$s = $ctx.MkSolver()

$expr =  $x * $x - $one # x*x- 1
$assert = $s.Assert($ctx.MkEq( $expr, $zero)) # x*x - 1 = 0

$s.Check()
$m = $s.Model
$m.Decls | % { "$($_.Name) -> $($m.ConstInterp($_))" }
```

this, however, returns

```
SATISFIABLE
x -> -1
```

This is a bit confusing to me, as I'd expect it to return two roots, 1 and -1

The more confusing it becomes when I try this in python (in google colab)

```
x = Int('x')
solve(x*x-1==0)
```

it says

[image]

What do I do wrong in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z3 (and SMT solvers in general) will return only one model for each call to `check`. If you want to find out "all-solutions" then you have to enumerate them. There are several different ways of doing so, see this answer [(Z3Py) checking all solutions for equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867611/z3py-checking-all-solutions-for-equation) in the Python context; which can be translated to other API's as well.

So, you're not doing anything wrong. You're just getting one possible model, as this is how the z3 API works.