# z3 python How select element in Array and store to file

Tags: python, z3, z3py

How create array of integer and show all array with this same element
A = [0..4,0..4,0..4]

i need print to screen each:
[0,0,0,0] and [1,1,1,1] and .... [4,4,4,4]

```py
    from z3 import *
    
    #A = [ Int('a%s' % i) for i in range(4) ]
    A = IntVector('a', 4)
    print( 'A = ', A )
    i = Int('i'); j = Int('j')
    
    r = Solver()
    r.add( i >= 0 ); r.add( i < 3 )
    r.add( j >= 0 ); r.add( j < 3 )
    #r.add( Select(A,i) == Select(A,j) )
    print(r.check())
    print(r.model())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't quite clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to generate all length-4 lists with same elements between 0 and 4? There could be many ways to encode that in z3; here's one approach:

```py
from z3 import *

A = Ints('a b c d')

s = Solver()

for a in A[1:]:
  s.add(A[0] == a)

s.add(A[0] >= 0)
s.add(A[0] <= 4)

for m in list(all_smt(s, A)):
  print(m)
```

Note that the above uses the function `all_smt` whose definition you can find at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70656700/936310

When run, the above prints:

```py
[b = 0, d = 0, c = 0, a = 0]
[b = 1, a = 1, c = 1, d = 1]
[b = 2, a = 2, c = 2, d = 2]
[b = 3, a = 3, c = 3, d = 3]
[b = 4, a = 4, c = 4, d = 4]
```

Of course, you can post-process the models in any particular way you want. In fact, if what you're trying to generate is simply the same elements always, you don't even need 4 variables, but I assume there's a reason why you wanted it that way. (Perhaps they come from some other part of your program?)

Comment: Is possible change this answer to using array? I need checking data using indexed element A = [ Int('a%s' % i) for i in range(4) ]
or if You can show me how checking each index A[3] != A[0] etc.

Comment: Why first line is not sorting? [b = 0, d = 0, c = 0, a = 0] if I use a vector or array it is possible too?

Comment: What’s printed is a python dictionary, which doesn’t have any ordering on fields. You can post process it to print it in any way you like. Vector would be similar, just different coding. SMTLib arrays are indexed by their entire domain unlike software arrays, so I wouldn’t recommend using them for this problem.

Comment: can You wrote example/answer with vector not dictionaty?